# How to output an empty string if array index is undefined (inside templates)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a function in PHP or a helper in Codeigniter which can do the following faster?

```
echo isset($c['some_var']) ? $c['some_var'] : '';
```

If I do just

`echo $c['some_var']`

and the index is undefined, I get a PHP warning.

I would like it to simply output an empty string if the variable is undefined or index unset.

Is there a CI helper or PHP way to output it?

Comment: I don't think so, but what you can do is create your own helper function to check if the index of an array exist, if not then print an empty string. Alternatively, you can eliminate errors but I don't think it's a good practice to keep errors hidden

Comment: What is the best way to do it? This is something I very often need, but am confused on how to handle it.

Comment: There should probably be some logic in the controller that sets the value of this index to '' to minimize the logic in your views. Suppressing errors is kind of hacky.

Comment: This works for arrays only as I've mentioned: `your_function($array_name, $index){return isset($array_name[$index]) ? $array_name[$index] : ""};` @Tool

Comment: @Amir Do you think I will significantly lower page performance if I output every variable with a helper? I have around 20 fields per page.

Comment: No worries about performance in that case ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I create a custom helper and add the following:

```
if(!function_exists('issetor'))
{
    function issetor(&$var, $default = NULL)
    {
        return isset($var)? $var : $default;
    }
}
```

**Edit**: As a note, I would strongly advise against error suppression. In all reality, the ternary operator is the best way to do this. Since I don't like writing that much code just to use a variable's value if set and NULL otherwise, I use the above helper function.

Example usage, related to code in your question:

```
echo issetor($c['some_var'], '');
```

or

```
$c['some_var'] = issetor($c['some_var'], '');
echo $c['some_var'];
```

whatever floats your boat.

**Edit**: Here is a helpful link regarding helpers in CodeIgniter:

- https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can supress the warning with the default PHP error control operator (@).

```
echo @$c['some_var'];
echo @$c['some_var']['go_deep']['deeper']; //this also works
```

Same for php shorttags

```
<?=@$c['some_key']?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Performance impact is minor see

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php#102543

"So while yes, there is some overhead, per iteration, we see that the @ operator added only .005 ms per call.  Not reason enough, imho, to avoid using the @ operator"

Comment: I wouldn't use the @operator because it has performance impact. The best way to acheive what OP wants to do is with the ternary function.

Comment: Performance impact? any source for that? because as far as i know that's not true

Comment: Read the manual or do test about it. There are countless example for this.

Comment: I'm unsure how this would impact me in the long term. If at one point I'll have +200 files using the '@' syntax, will I regret it? Won't it sometimes make it harder to debug for other people?

Comment: I don't think so 0.005ms delay for every @ that means 200 @ operators in one request with an total delay of 1ms you wont notice that

Answer (score 0):

Just this:

```
 print '' or isset($c['some_var']);
```

Comment: I like this more then my example because here you don't use 'some_var' index twice.

Comment: @Tool Yeah! It's just simple!